# Evaluation $ \lim_{x \to - \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{1000} \frac{x^k}{k!} $

Tags: integration

$$
\lim_{x \to - \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{1000} \frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
How do I evaluate such a limit? Is it possible to use the $e^x$ series here to conclude? I know that the $e^x$ series doesn't converge, and it doesn't cater to a finite number of terms, but can we use the squeeze theorem to evaluate the limiting value? Can someone provide a formal answer?

Comment: It doesn't look like it converges to me...  Had the upper limit on the summation been $1,2,$ or $3$ then it clearly diverges.  Why should it being $1000$ as the upper limit instead change the behavior that much?

Comment: Note that $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\left[\lim\limits_{K\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^K\frac{x^k}{k!}\right]$ is not the same as $\lim\limits_{K\to\infty}\left[\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^K\frac{x^k}{k!}\right]$.  In the first limit, you eventually have $k$ get larger than $x$ for any finite value of $x$ which helps the series converge.  That is not the case for the second limit.

Comment: This is just a regular polynomial, and polynomials blow up at infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sum is a polynomial of degree $1000$ with leading coefficient $\frac{1}{1000!} > 0$.  As $x \rightarrow -\infty$, this polynomial goes to $\infty$.

The last bit is a standard calculus fact.  One way to get at it is: \begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \sum_{n=0}^d a_n x^n &= \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} a_d x^d \sum_{n=0}^d \frac{a_n}{a_d}x^{n-d}  \\
&= \begin{cases} \textrm{sgn}(a_d)\infty ,& \text{$d$ even}  \\  \textrm{sgn}(a_d)(-\infty) ,& \text{$d$ odd}\end{cases}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
where we have used the [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).
(Sometimes that this new sum contributes nothing of interest is more evident when expressed as
$$  a_d x^d + a_{d-1} x^{d-1} + \cdots + a_0  \\  = a_d x^d \left( 1 + \frac{a_{d-1}}{a_d}x^{-1} + \cdots + \frac{a_0}{a_d} x^{-d}\right)  \text{.)}$$

Comment: This is quite intuitive, but can you provide with a satisfactory explanation as to why the limit should be infinity?